# How to track button click events in android analyitcs api v4

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have few buttons on Main Activity and I want to track each button click. I am using Android Google Analytics API v4.

Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp)this.getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    t.setScreenName("Home");
    t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
```

Here is the button code:

```
public void button1(View v){
    //Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CategoryListActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("name", "button1");
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
}
```

I have tried adding this:

```
t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
    .setCategory("Events")
    .setAction("Pressed button")
    .build());
```

like this

```
public void button1(View v){
    //Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CategoryListActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("name", "button1");
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

    t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
        .setCategory("Events")
        .setAction("Pressed Start Button")
        .build());

}
```

but it always gives me the error:

```
t cannot be resolved
```

This is my xml file code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape4"
    android:onClick="Button1"
    android:text=" Button1 " />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code:
first of all create this class to handle of all transaction with Google Analytics:

```
public class GoogleAnalyticsHelper {

private Tracker mGaTracker = null;
private static String TAG = "GoogleAnalyticsHelper";
private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-xxxxxxxx-x";

public GoogleAnalyticsHelper()    
{
public void init(Context ctx) {
    try {

        if (mGaTracker == null && ctx != null)
        {
            mGaTracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(ctx).newTracker(PROPERTY_ID);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(GoogleAnalyticsHelper.TAG,"init, e="+e);
    }
}

public void SendScreenNameGoogleAnalytics(String screenName, Context iCtx)
{
    init(iCtx);

    mGaTracker.setScreenName(screenName);
    mGaTracker.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());

}


public void SendEventGoogleAnalytics(Context iCtx,String iCategoryId, String iActionId, String iLabelId)
{
    init(iCtx);

        // Build and send an Event.
        mGaTracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
            .setCategory(iCategoryId)
            .setAction(iActionId)
            .setLabel(iLabelId)
            .build());

     }
  }
```

then add this code to your main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  GoogleAnalyticsHelper mGoogleHelper;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    InitGoogleAnalytics();
    SendScreenNameGoogleAnalytics();
}


private void InitGoogleAnalytics()
{           
    mGoogleHelper = new GoogleAnalyticsHelper();        
    mGoogleHelper.init(MainActivity.this);      
}

private void SendScreenNameGoogleAnalytics()
{

    mGoogleHelper.SendScreenNameGoogleAnalytics("MainActivity 1",MainActivity.this);
}

private void SendEventGoogleAnalytics(String iCategoryId, String iActionId,    String iLabelId)
{

   mGoogleHelper.SendEventGoogleAnalytics(MainActivity.this,iCategoryId,iActionId,iLabelId );
}



public void button1(View v){

  SendEventGoogleAnalytics("Main","btn1","button1 clicked" );

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CategoryListActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("name", "button1");
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
}
```

It's work for me.